# Inserting data into mongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

i seem to be unable to upload data into my mongo db hosted on atlas. I have copied the exact steps posted here. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_insert.asp

```
import pymongo
import requests

url= "mongodb://jordan:*********@jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017,jordandb-shard-00-01-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017,jordandb-shard-00-02-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=JordanDB-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
mydb = client.test
mycol = mydb["customers"]
mydict = {"name":"John", "adress":"Highway 37"}
x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)

print(client.list_database_names())
```

I am receiving a timeout error. Every line works until i get to the insert line (x = ....). I am using pycharm and python 3.7. However I have also tried this on jupyter and have received the same error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056),jordandb-shard-00-01-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056),jordandb-shard-00-02-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Here are the steps I am following to get the url
[image]
[image]

Comment: That connection string looks offly odd. And the stack trace just as odd. Are you sure the hostname should be comma separated multiple times with port numbers?

Comment: Torxed, I add the steps I took to get the connection string + pictures

Comment: Well the problem is that the certificate is self-signed. Or that your computer can't find the CA for this certificate. Supplying it manually might help: `MongoClient(..., ssl_ca_certs='/path/to/ca.pem')` or worst case, do `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE`. see [docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#certificate-verification-policy) for more info.

Comment: Hi torxed thanks for your help, but this is not working for me. Is there a way to remove the self signed feature?

Comment: `ssl=true` in your URL specifies that it's going to use SSL. If your supplier of this mongodb requires you to use SSL *(which, you should.. there's no reason not to do it at all.. **nope**! Not one single usecase)* you have to. You can use the `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE` to ignore certificate errors. Again, you shouldn't do this unless you really have to. Get the certificate CA chain and load it, it's not as hard as it sounds. You can even supply it in the URL via `?ssl_ca_certs=/path/to/ca.pem` - which your supplier should have told you in their fancy tool. Sounds like a support ticket tbh.

Comment: There's also the possability that your computer time is wrong, you don't have a certificate chain installed (gentoo, arch linux, etc). Which also is [described](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors) in the docs :) You can verify the certificate by issuing this command on any linux computer: `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername jordandb-shard-00-0  0-ykcna.mongodb.net -connect jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017 </dev/null` which will tell you that the certificate is valid, you're missing the DigiCert Inc chain on your computer.

Comment: OMG Torxed, I switched to my desktop from my mac and it worked! It was the time issue. Thanks so much. Please post in answer section so I can give you credit

Comment: Done. Glad it all worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons for this.
The most obvious one would be that you're missing the certificate chain.

You can get the chain information from issuing:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net -connect jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017 </dev/null
```

Which will tell you that it's from DigiCert. So either you're missing that certificate chain in your local certificate store *(some distro's might need you to install a root ca trust)*. But if you do have root ca's installed. It's time to check the validation times on the cert.
If you add `| openssl x509 -noout -dates` you'll get the valid dates for this certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net -connect jordandb-shard-00-00-ykcna.mongodb.net:27017 </dev/null  | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Which tells you the certificate is from DigiCert.
And the certificate is valid from `7/02-19 00:00 GMT` to `11/2-19 12:00 GMT`.
Running `date` in any terminal should hopefully tell you that you're in between these two dates.

In any other case, I would say this is due to a self signed certificate.
In which case you would need to do one of two things:

```
MongoClient(..., ssl_ca_certs='/path/to/ca.pem')
MongoClient(..., ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

To either supply your custom CA or tell Mongo to ignore certificate validation *(the later being the worst possible option. Even if you say "I won't forget to fix that later", heh)*.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use pymongo default function

```
connObj = MongoClient(MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT)
connObj[MONGO_DB].authenticate(MONGO_UNAME, MONGO_PASSWD)
```